# why does my javascript for loop create an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, debugging

I am taking a Javascript class and I'm working on my own project. I am currently stuck on a for loop and was hoping someone could help.

This is the code I have written:

```
console.log(`-----WATER REFILL STRATEGY-----`);
console.log(totalWaterToDrink, waterPerHour(raceInfo.tempHigh));

let waterHourFinal = waterPerHour(raceInfo.tempHigh);
console.log(waterHourFinal);

for (let j = totalWaterToDrink; j > 0; j - waterHourFinal) {
  console.log(`${j - waterHourFinal} water left`);
}

for (let i = 0; i < raceTime; i++) {
  console.log(`Hour ${i + 1}: drink $INPUT OZ PER HR HERE.`);
}
```

The problem exists with the For loop involving J. I get an infinite output and I am not sure why.

This is literally my first coding question to the public ever so be nice. ;)

Thanks! (and if there is a better way to ask questions, please let me know)

My code:

[image: 1]

The output:

[image: 2]

Comment: You never change the value of `j` in the loop, so it's always `> 0`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `-=` instead of `-`

```
for (let j = totalWaterToDrink; j > 0; j -= waterHourFinal) {
  console.log(`${j - waterHourFinal} water left`);
}
```

Comment: That totally worked. Thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `j = j - waterHourFinal` instead of `j - waterHourFinal`

```
for (let j = totalWaterToDrink; j > 0; j -= waterHourFinal) {
   console.log(`${j - waterHourFinal} water left`);
}
```

Short hand for `j = j - waterHourFinal` could be `j -= waterHourFinal`